# Anchor a label to move with an object

Tags: c#, image, animation, anchor

I have an elevator program.

The lift is represented as image object which moves to request people on the floors they are on.

I currently have a label which represents how many people are on the lift and is of type int.

I want this label to be anchored to the lift image while it moves to show how many people are currently in the lift while it moves. How would I go about doing this?

Below is the code for the lift image:

```
    public Lift(PictureBox limg, int[] fy, int sf, frmLiftSim mf, int id, int peopleCounter)
    {
        liftImage = limg; // this is the image for the lift
        floor_y = fy;
        initFloor = sf;
        mainForm = mf;
        liftID = id;
counter = peopleCounter; // this is the people counter for the lift

        liftImage.Top = floor_y[initFloor];  // Move lift to the start position
        currentFloor = initFloor;            // Set the lift's current position

        mainForm.AddToLog("Lift " + liftID + " initialised. Start floor: " + currentFloor);

        dtMove.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20); // time
        dtMove.Tick += new EventHandler(dtMove_Tick);

        dtWait.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        dtWait.Tick += new EventHandler(dtWait_Tick);

        mainForm.UpdateFloorDisp(currentFloor, liftID);
    }
```

Comment: I would put the PictureBox and the Labels in a Panel via `Panel1.Controls.Add(...)` and move the Panel instead of the PictureBox.

Comment: Yes but the panel would then need to be converted into an image object for my code to work

Comment: **No**, you would have to refactor your code.